# FF addon toolbar, how do you allow items to be dragged onto it?

Tags: firefox-addon

FF addon toolbar, how do you allow items to be dragged onto it?

Comment: programming related how? Perhaps try Superuser.com

Comment: Yes how do I program it into my current addon? Currently my addon toolbar doesn't allow me to drag and drop say the search box onto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the correct answer is: adding customizable="true" to the toolbar tag will allow you to drop icons onto your toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [*Drag and drop*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DragDrop/Drag_and_Drop) documentation.

Basically you have to listen to the `dragenter` event:

> `dragenter`
>
> Fired when the mouse is first moved over an element while a drag is occuring. **A listener for this event should indicate whether a drop is allowed over this location.** If there are no listeners, or the listeners perform no operations, then a drop is not allowed by default. This is also the event to listen to if you want to provide feedback that a drop is allowed such as displaying a highlight or insertion marker. For information about this, see [Specifying Drop Targets](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/Drag_Operations#droptargets).

Comment: The customizable attribute determines if the user can customize the toolbar. You should normally set this to true, unless you have strong reasons not to want users changing your toolbar.